# Getting point less that 1 unit apart in a pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I have a pandas data frame (df) with more that 18000 readings/points (Id with X [East] - Y readings [North]). I want to iterate through df and get all the points that is less than 1 unit away or apart from one another.

[Screenshot of df.head()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDASh.jpg)

My current code does work by using 2 for loops and iterating through the rows and calculating the distance and printing the cases where the if conditions are true.

```
for i, j in df.iterrows():
pnt, east, north = j[1], j[2], j[3]
for l, k in df1.iterrows():
    pnt1, east1, north1 = k[1], k[2], k[3]
    dist = math.hypot(east - east1, north - north1)
    if dist > 0 and dist < 1:
        print('Point {} is {}units away from point {}'.format(pnt, str(dist), pnt1))
```

Not sure if it was needed but I duplicated the dataframe to df1 to see if the code will run faster. Although this is working it taking forever to run and wanted to know how to improve the speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Straight Forward Method

As you have not provided a good way to get to the real data, I have created a sample set for demonstration purpose:

```
 HoleID      East     North
      A  1.000000  2.000000
      B  1.351590  2.756961
      C  2.265317  3.174667
      D  2.599347  3.876338
      E  2.770851  4.407866
```

I guess what you try to achieve is to compare each point with every other point and calculate the distance.

To achieve this you can join the dataframe with itself on dummy variable `x` which is the same for all entries, calculate the distance and filter out whatever has a distance < 1 (no need to run calculate the square root for that).

```
df = pd.read_clipboard()

df["x"] = 1
result = (
    df.merge(df, on="x")
    .assign(
        distance=lambda x: (x["East_x"] - x["East_y"]) ** 2
        + (x["North_x"] - x["North_y"]) ** 2
    )
    .loc[
        lambda x: (x["distance"] < 1) & (x["distance"] > 0),
        ["HoleID_x", "HoleID_y", "distance"],
    ]
)
result["distance"] = result["distance"].apply(math.sqrt)
print(result)
```

The result still contains duplicates (A -> B is the same distance as B -> A):

```
   HoleID_x HoleID_y  distance
1         A        B  0.834629
5         B        A  0.834629
13        C        D  0.777122
17        D        C  0.777122
19        D        E  0.558512
23        E        D  0.558512
```

### Using numpy and scipy

The `scipy` package contains the `pdist` function, which calculates the pairwise distances between points. This might come to your rescue, and might even work with a big dataset as yours.

To use it try the following:

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import squareform, pdist

# calculate the pairwise distances
distances = pdist(df[["East", "North"]])
# now we select only those between 0 and 1, and create a symmetric matrix from the result
distances = squareform(np.where((distances < 1) & (distances > 0), distances, 0))
# finally we take the lower triangle of the matrix, create a dataframe
# and flatten it so we see every pair only once.
result = (
    pd.DataFrame(np.tril(distances), columns=df.HoleID, index=df.HoleID)
    .unstack()
    .loc[lambda x: x > 0]
)
print(result)
```

The result we get is

```
HoleID  HoleID
A       B         0.834629
C       D         0.777122
D       E         0.558512
dtype: float64
```

I would be interested to hear if you can apply this to your whole dataframe at once.

Comment: Thank you for this. Looks as if my data set is to large for my machine. I am getting the following error: 

MemoryError: Unable to allocate 20.2 GiB for an array with shape (8, 338192100) and data type float64

Will try to make the data set smaller

Comment: One possibility to avoid running into memory problems would be to do a mix between your suggestion and my solution: split df into multiple chunks, run the merge on each chunk ( `df.merge(df[slice], on='x').assign(...)`) and combine the results. You would have to try how big you can make the slices so it still fits into the memory.

Comment: That worked like a bomb. Did even had to do a mix. Thanks